# Run wine command from python

Tags: wine, python, apache2

I have Apache that serves a web service with a python script. I trie to execute a WINE command from python, but nothing happens...

```
command1 = 'dir > test.txt'
command2 = 'wine someexecutable.exe inputfile outpufile'
p = subprocess.call(command1, shell=True)
p = subprocess.call(command2, shell=True)
```

The command1 is normally executed, and I get a test.txt file. It seems that command2 is not executed at all... If I execute it manually from the shell with www-data user, the command2 exectues and I get the output file -> `not a permission problem`. Is there something to configure to allow python to execute wine commands ?

Comment: Could it be because wine needs X running?.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is generally correct but you need to give Wine a more explicit path to your executable. You can see what is going on in the return error:

```
>>> subprocess.call("wine someexecutable.exe inputfile outpufile", shell=True)
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\someexecutable.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks Oli, but I already wrote the path with that syntax. I have no Apache error... the command seems to not execute at all

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work, as long as wine
is installed properly:

```
subprocess.call("./filename.exe", shell=True)
```

I was able to get it to work without calling wine directly, hopefully the same works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import commands

command1 = 'dir > test.txt'
command2 = 'wine someexecutable.exe inputfile outpufile'

cmd1 = commands.getoutput(command1)
cmd2 = commands.getoutput(command2)
```

***Note***: sometimes OS pipe buffer might get filled with output being redirected to a pipe, thus try commands module instead of subprocess for this task!

Comment: From the Python docs: `Deprecated since version 2.6: The commands module has been removed in Python 3. Use the subprocess module instead.`

Comment: You didn't have to give me a down vote! This isn't technically wrong; just not suitable in the new version, that's all. It works perfectly in 2.6. Jeez.

Comment: It's just bad practice. Why would you write code which you know is deprecated and won't work in the future? Python 3 isn't new anymore. If you write new code, write it correct.